# AudioQueueLevelMeterStateで取得したレベルを音波の振幅に対応させたいがわからない

Tags: swift

まず、一般的な部分についてです。
リニアPCM-16bit音源のダイナミックレンジについて質問です。

よく解説に16bitは2の16乗まで表せるので
20*log10(2^16)~96.32dBまで表現可能という解説を見ます。
ですが、波動の場合振幅は(上限-下限)/2になると思います。
だとすると振幅の最大値は2^15が最大値ではないかと思いました。

すると、振幅のピークは
20*log10(2^15)~90.3程度になると思うのですが、
どうして96dBまで扱うことができるのでしょうか。

AudioQueueLevelMeterStateの
mPeakPower/mAveragePowerに対して96.3を足せば、
ほぼ実際の音量レベルに対応するのでしょうか。
とすると取得した音波のレベルをLとして10^(L/20)が振幅バージョンのRMS値に相当するでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

何故2で割らなければいけないのでしょうか？16ビットで、音量・音圧を表すのですから、無音=0から、最大音量=2＾16　ではないですか？

@shin-ichiさんが勘違いしておられるのは、サンプリングレートがナイキスト周波数を超えると標本化されなくなので、録音できる周波数はサンプリングレートの1/2であることと混同しておられる気がします。

こちらの勘違いの可能性も充分ありますが、その際はご容赦下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　wavファイルのデータ中では音波の波形が記録されていると認識しております。すると、振幅の最大値が+-符号の1bitぶんを除き2^15となると思ったためです。波形データの他に音圧は別で記録されていたりするのでしょうか。

Comment: 上記コメントを補足しますと、波形データの振幅としては2^15がmaxになると思っています。何故ならば、振幅は波形データの絶対値の間だからです。RMSにしても定義から振幅の最大値を超えることはないと思います。とするとそれをフーリエ変換した正規化されたスペクトルでも値の最大値は2^15なのではないかと思うのですが、違いますでしょうか。正規化せず、最大値を2^16になるようにスペクトルを求めれば良いかと思いましたが、内部でそういったことをやっているとは思えなかったので、このような質問をいたしました。波形データの中身が具体的にどんな物理量と紐づいているか理解していないためかもしれないと思いました。

Comment: 調べてみたら`mPeakPower`/`mAveragePower`は、0が最大値で、マイナスの値が返ってくるそうです。

Comment: @shin-ichi さん、sin波のようなものを思い浮かべて0を中心に(-1)...(1)で振れるようなものだけを考えているのでうまく理解できないのだと思います。(0)...(1)で振れる波もれっきとした波でその振幅は1と考えられます。(-32768)...(32767)で振れる波との比をdB表示したものが96.3dBとなるわけです。

Comment: @Чайкаさん、ありがとうございます。@OOPerさん、波動の場合、振幅の定義としてはやはり、振動の中心から最大値までとなっており、いただいた例だと振幅は1/2になるはずです。そこで思ったのですが、最小振幅が1/2でそれに対して2^15の振幅の比は2^16となります。これをもって音量が2^16まで表現できると言っているのではないかと。